# Access template properties which are stored in resources

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, resourcedictionary, gridcontrol

I have a derived devexpress grid control which sets some template for the indicator row:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="{dxgt:TableViewThemeKey ResourceKey=IndicatorWidth, ThemeName=Office2016White}">300</sys:Double>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="{dxgt:RowIndicatorThemeKey ResourceKey=RowTemplate, ThemeName=Office2016White}">
      <Grid Name="IndicatorGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="35" Name="IndicatorColumnRowNumber" SharedSizeGroup="RowNumberGroup" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="200" Name="IndicatorColumnDescription" SharedSizeGroup="DescriptionGroup" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="200" Name="IndicatorColumnSource" SharedSizeGroup="SourceGroup" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        //...
    </DataTemplate>
</dxg:GridControl.Resources>
```

Right now the width of the indicator column is fixed to 300. Now I want the width of the row being calculated by the columns defined in the second part. I know I can access the indicator width of the view via the code behind as well but I'm not able to access the template controls in the code behind

```
var view = ((TableView)this.View);
view.IndicatorWidth = IndicatorColumnRowNumber.Width /* can not be found */ + ...
```

Since they live in the resources in the xaml. As I understand this is also not supposed to happen. What is the best way to implement this? Maybe extract the definitions in the code behind?

**Edit:**
Here is a picture of the table

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but if you want to access your resource in code behind you can go about it like this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyResource">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var resource = MyGrid.Resources["MyResource"];
        var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate) resource;
    }
```

You have additional tools to obtain any defined resources.
The methods FrameworkElement.FindResource and FrameworkElement.TryFindResource will search for resources from the element you specified and up the visual tree until the main application and including any themes you have setup. From the MS reference:

[FrameworkElement.FindResource documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also notice that the Resources dictionary and the FindResource methods accept an object key (not a string). This suits your case since your key is a RowIndicatorThemeKey object. You can instantiate such an object and set the ResourceKey property to the "RowTemplate" value and search for your resource like that.

In general solutions for problems such as yours can be achieved without requiring code behind though, if you provide some more information perhaps we can find a solution based on bindings.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I would love to do that in the XAML. I'm trying to rephrase it: The total indicator column with is set in first resource entry. I want that to be then same as all the columns (currently 435, but it want to set it to "auto")

Comment: You could bind to the element "IndicatorGrid" and to its ActualWidth property: `{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=IndicatorGrid}'

Comment: But I want it the other way around: The grid should define the needed size and the indicator width should then be adopted accordingly

Comment: I see. The thing is that you cannot bind to the Width property of a ColumnDefinition. Instead you can use the star syntax. In your case you want the latter two columns to be ~6 times the width of the first so you can specify the first column width to be `*` and for the two others `6*`. Now the indicator grid will take up all space automatically (if positioned correctly in the template) and the columns will expand in all available space while maintaining your ratios

Comment: I do not want to bind the width of the column, that is defined in the xaml (as in my question). There is an overall property `IndicatorWidth` of the view which needs to be the same size otherwise either you can not see all columns or there will be empty space on the right side